# How can I 'release' an application after opening it with using a Python script?

Tags: python, python-2.7, win32com

I am starting with Python and want to use it to dispatch an application with win32com (the application is PTV Vissim, for traffic modelling), however, after the script is done with whatever I ask it to do, it closes and kills Vissim with it too.

Is there a way to avoid this?

i.e. I want the Python script to finish but leaving the dispatched application open for the user to keep working with it.

This is the code I'm using:

```
import win32com.client as com
import os

# Opening a new Vissim window
Vissim = com.Dispatch("Vissim.Vissim")

# Define filename and save as new model
Path = "C:\ModelWIP\Vissim\Script_test"
Filename = os.path.join(Path, "My_Model.inpx")
Vissim.SaveNetAs(Filename)

# Keeps python command line open until the user confirms
raw_input('Press any key to exit')
```

The final bit with `raw_input` is there to keep the script from finishing and therefore keeping the Vissim instance alive, this is the only solution I've found so far.

Comment: You should start your script from another script with `subprocess.Popen`.

Comment: @ipaleka thanks, I'll try this and get back when I figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

Can you open Vissim with the os.system command? If you can, it will let you terminate the Python process and keep the Vissim instance opened.

E.g.: 
`os.system("start vissim.exe")`

Comment: This works opening vissim as an independent instance from the script but won't execute the rest of the instructions.  I tried this: ````Vissim = os.system('"C:\Program Files\PTV Vision\PTV Vissim 9\Exe\VISSIM90.exe"')```` instead of the `com.Dispatch` line.

Comment: Just to add to the comment above, I've just figured out this happens because by doing so, the instance I'm calling is not 'controlled' (sorry if using the wrong terminology here) via the COM server.  Maybe I need to keep the script open after all?

Comment: I appears so, similar to how you need to keep the prompt open after invoking anaconda, for example, otherwise it closes both the prompt and anaconda.